# React, Bootstrap Nav

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, nav

I'm new in React world, and stucked on beginning.

Trying to make **Nav** menu with **react-bootstrap**.Everything works fine until Nav.Item is changed.
*onSelect()* should change activeKey, and consequently change style on clicked Nav.Item.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.tsx:

```
import NavMenu from "./components/NavMenu";

const navItems: any = [
    {id: 0, name: "Home", link:"home"},
    {id: 1, name: "First", link:"first"},
    {id: 2, name: "Second", link:"second"}
]


const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <NavMenu navItems={navItems}/>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

NavMenu/idnex.tsx:

```
import {useState} from "react";
import {Nav} from "react-bootstrap";

const NavMenu = (props: any) => {
    const {navItems} = props;
    const [activeNav, setActiveNav] = useState('first')

    const handleClick = (eventKey: any) => setActiveNav(eventKey);

    console.log(activeNav)

    return (
        <div>
            <Nav
                defaultActiveKey="home"
                className="flex-column"
                activeKey={activeNav}
                variant="pills"
                navbar={true}
                onSelect={handleClick}
            >
            { navItems.map((item: any) => {
                const {id, link, name} = item;

                    return (
                        <Nav.Item key={id}>
                            <Nav.Link href={link}
                                      eventKey={link}>
                                {name}
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                    );
                })}
            </Nav>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NavMenu;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nav-test-case",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Change is visible for one moment, and then it just rollback to default setted Nav.Item.
So it's not selected clicked Nav.Item, than the one set by default.

In Console I see change of variable from log

> console.log(activeNav)

but whole page refreshes and log is reseted as well

[moment before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECSw3.jpg)

Please if someone can point me in the right direction to find out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: if you are using react developer tools can you check that activeNav state variable is set or not, or either it reverts back to previous value of state or either null.

Comment: It's changes value for a split second until page refreshes, after refresh value is back to default. I edited post with Console print scrn moment before page is refreshed.

Comment: Maybe `console.log(eventKey);` to confirm it has the desired value? Also, not sure if handleClick is bound properly to the NavMenu instance. I am also new to react, so sorry if I am not much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see it you want to have links working inside the app - but what you did is simply the way you can go to implement links to external pages.

The way to go is to use `react-router-dom`.

1. Add `react-router-dom` with your package manager.
2. Wrap your application with the `BrowserRouter` and define the possible Routes of your page in the `Switch` that defines all possible pages of your app and the according components.

```
 <StrictMode>
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
       <Route exact path="/home" component={App} />
       <Route exact path="/first" component={App} />
       <Route exact path="/second" component={App} />
     </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
 </StrictMode>,
```

3. Use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` and declare your nav links as those:

```
<Nav.Item key={id}>
 <Nav.Link as={Link} to={link} eventKey={link}>
   {name}
 </Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
```

That should be it.
You can see it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-cherry-8hnu9

Comment: It worked thanks, actually I did some similar example with Router. But I missed "as={Link} to={link}" It seems like that was crucial for wanted behavior